# Gstreamer's glimagesink element update when client window size changes (Using Python)

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm developing an app with python and Gstreamer under Windows.

The pipeline that i'm using it's very simple:

```
gltestsrc(pattern=13)->capsfilter(caps=video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory),format=RGBA,framerate=30/1,height=2160,width=3840)->glimagesink
```

All seems to run fine, but when i resize the client window (set by set_window_handle())  the content rendered by glimagesink is not updated to fit the new size of the window.

The docs of glimagesink and PyGObject are outdated and/or incomplete, so they are not a very usefull resource in this case.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

With gst-launch-1.0 all runs fine because the glimagesink shows an internal window that update the content while resizing.

The things become rare when i use my own Gtk window (on top of Python 3)

And the gstreamer version is 1.8.1

Comment: what about trying that in gst-launch? For me it resizes just fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with gstreamer 1.6.3 (whats your version?) `gst-launch-1.0 gltestsrc pattern=13 ! "video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory),format=RGBA,framerate=30/1,height=2160,width=3840" ! glimagesink`

Comment: Are you sure that the content view of your window changes its size when you resize the window? Could be that you resize the window but no the containing element of this window?